# How to grab a single element passed from express JSON array and output in Jade

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, pug

I have an array incoming from Express to a Jade template that looks like this:

```
 [{ id: 11,
  firstname: 'asdfasdf',
  lastname: 'asdfasdf',
 },
 { id: 12,
  firstname: 'asdfadf',
  lastname: 'asdfasdf',
 }]
```

I want to grab one of these elements and display it along with its properties on the page.
I have read several other answers here but none seem to answer my question/work properly.

I have tried,

```
#{data[0].id}
!{data[0].id}
#{data.id[0]}
data.id[0]
data[0].id
```

...and countless other combinations, how can i print this out properly?
I know my data object is being passed in correctly because I can iterate through it using a for loop elsewhere in my page.  But if I only want to grab ONE element ONLY from the array, how can i achieve this?

Is this even possible without looping through the entire json array object?

UPDATE: my problem was due to the array structure being different than what I initially thought it was.  My mistake, the correct way to access elements is using

```
#{data[0].id}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of JSON objects so you need to iterate it through

```
 var newObject =  [{ id: 11,
  firstname: 'asdfasdf',
  lastname: 'asdfasdf',
 },
 { id: 12,
  firstname: 'asdfadf',
  lastname: 'asdfasdf',
 }];


for (var i = 0; i < newObject.length; i++) {
    var object = newObject[i];
    for (var property in object) {
        alert('item ' + i + ': ' + property + '=' + object[property]);
    }
}
```

or

```
var newObject =  "[{ id: 11,firstname: 'asdfasdf',lastname: 'asdfasdf',},{ id: 12, firstname: 'asdfadf', lastname: 'asdfasdf',}]";
var obj = eval(newObject);
alert(obj[0].id);
```

Comment: yes, i understand JSON and as I have said in my post above, I have already successfully accessed each element in a for loop already.  However, I am wondering if there is a way to directly access one of the json objects within the array, WITHOUT having to iterate through all of it first, in Jade.

Comment: you could use eval() function as well if you could convert the value to String